# Train Cascade Object Detector bounding box out of bound?

Tags: matlab, object-detection, vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to train a cascade object detector using the built-in function in Matlab (vision toolbox). However, the following message came up after running the command.

*

```
Error using trainCascadeObjectDetector (line 245)
Error reading instance 1 from image 2, bounding box possibly out of image bounds.
```

*

I don't understand why the bounding box can be out of bounds. All the parameters for my positive images are set up correctly (starting point x,y, width, and height. I used `createMask(h)` to create a mask and find the minimum coordinates for x and y to be starting point and max-min for each dimension to be the width and height), and the negative images (as far as I know) are just images without any setup needed.

Anyone ever ran into the same problem? How did you solve it?

EDIT:
Here's the code. I don't have the toolbox for training the "data" struct, so I wrote one myself

```
positive_samples=struct;
list=dir('my_folder_name_which_I_took_out');

L=length(list)-3; %Set L to be the length of the image list.
for i=1:length(list)
    positive_samples(i).imageFilename=list(i).name;
end
positive_samples(:,1)=[]; %first 3 lines do not contain file names
positive_samples(:,1)=[];
positive_samples(:,1)=[];

for j=1:1
    imshow(positive_samples(j).imageFilename);
    title(positive_samples(j).imageFilename);
    h=imrect;
    h1=createMask(h);
    I=imread(positive_samples(j).imageFilename);
    [le, wi, hi]=size(I);
    tempmat=[];
    count=1;
    for l=1:le
        for m=1:wi
            if h1(l,m)==1
                tempmat(count,1)=l;
                tempmat(count,2)=m;
                count=count+1;
            end
        end
    end
    positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,1)=min(tempmat(:,1));
    positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,2)=min(tempmat(:,2));
    positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,3)=max(tempmat(:,2))-min(tempmat(:,2));
    positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,4)=max(tempmat(:,1))-min(tempmat(:,1));
    imtool close all
end
trainCascadeObjectDetector('animalfinder.xml', positive_samples, 'my_neative_folder_name', 'FalseAlarmRate', 0.2, 'NumCascadeStages', 3);
```

sorry if it's messy......

Comment: Please provide code which allows to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not run the code, because I don't own the toolbox, but the following lines are very "suspicious":

```
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,1)=min(tempmat(:,1));
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,2)=min(tempmat(:,2));
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,3)=max(tempmat(:,2))-min(tempmat(:,2));
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,4)=max(tempmat(:,1))-min(tempmat(:,1));
```

I would expect:

```
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,1)=min(tempmat(:,2));
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,2)=min(tempmat(:,1));
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,3)=max(tempmat(:,2))-min(tempmat(:,2));
positive_samples(j).objectBoundingBoxes(1,4)=max(tempmat(:,1))-min(tempmat(:,1));
```

Some suggestions to shorten your code, they are not related to the problem:

You can shorten line 4 to 9 to a single line, avoiding the loop: `[positive_samples(1:L).im]=list(4:end).name`

And this loop can be replaced as well:

```
tempmat=[];
count=1;
for l=1:le
    for m=1:wi
        if h1(l,m)==1
            tempmat(count,1)=l;
            tempmat(count,2)=m;
            count=count+1;
        end
    end
end
```

shorter and faster code:

```
[y,x]=find(h1);
tempmat=[y x];
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for improving my code. For the first part, since objectBoundingBoxes(1,3) should take the width of the box, the column coordinates should be read (which is stored in :,2). This is why I set it up this way.

Comment: @JChao: Another time I messed up the coordinate system. The 'y'-Dimension is the first dimension and points from up to down if we are talking about image processing in matlab...

Comment: @JChao: I'm now totally confused by the different coordinate systems, but I think my updated answer is correct.

Comment: Hey thanks! after changing the coordinates, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to label your positive samples. The Computer Vision System Toolbox now includes the [Training Image Labeler app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html) (as of release 2014a). If you do not have R2014a you should try the [Cascade Training GUI app](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39627-cascade-training-gui-specify-ground-truth).

Comment: yea I realize that, but I can't use it since I don't have 2014 version. Therefore I'll just to write one on my own haha

Comment: There is also a labeling app on MATLAB Central.  I have added a link to that in the answer.  Try it before writing your own.